# Where can I find normal bank-operated ATMs in Playa de las Americas, Tenerife

Tags: applications, payment-cards, atms, mobile-apps, fraud

Is there an app or a website that presents ”bank-operated” ATMs around the world? In sweden we use https://bankomat.se/ to find all bank-operated ATMs.

Right now I’m looking for an ATM in Playa de las Americas, Tenerife.

I have gotten ripped of by one of **Euronet** ATMs, which added a 10% fee (”fake” high exchange rate”), so it is important I do not use "independent" ATMs, such as **Travelex, Euronet, Moneybox, Your Cash, Cardpoint, and Cashzone**, since these all have high fees and may try to trick you with "dynamic currency conversion."

Comment: This looks like a rant only weakly disguised as a question.

Comment: The rant content has now taken a second place. It could be a bit less still but I think it is acceptable now.

Comment: Use the international ATMs recommended by your own bank/card issuer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find a bank. Most banks these days have ATMs, and an ATM at or in a bank will be affiliated with the bank, and not one of the "independent" systems. A quick search on Google Maps shows lots of banks.

Comment: If you are really fortunate then you will find a closely affiliated bank to your own. For instance I have an account with BBVA in the US so I would use the BBVA ATMs in Tenerife for the lowest possible fees/rates.